# Function for amplification of probabilities

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

To simplify my task, let's just say that we have a situation when we have to choose a point and we have `N=2:7` points to choose from. We have a criteria by which probabilities are built, but the difference of calculated probabilities is very weak.

For example, we got `N = 3`, and probabilities are `[0.31 0.38 0.31]`. (Some points may have equal probability to be chosen). Or, for another example, `N = 5` and probabilities are 
`[0.2004  0.2011 0.1998 0.1999 0.1987]`

What we need - is to amplify the difference of probabilities - to make the biggest probability very strong, and others - very weak.

For example:
`F_amp([0.31 0.38 0.31])` returns `[0.11 0.78 0.11]`,

or `F_amp([0.2004 0.2011 0.1998 0.1999 0.1987])` returns
`[0.2 0.5 0.12 0.13 0.05]`

**The question is** - what function to use for this task? 
We can't change the physical meaning of criteria - our criteria is just as we have - we just have to exaggerate the fact that point with highest probability will be chosen with significantly larger chance.

P.S. Sorry, if I have chosen wrong stackexchange-forum for this question. Feel free to correct or move question if needed.